# C++ program cant find mistake

Tags: c++, arrays

this program creates  random number array where  elements wit arguments 1,3,5,7...,19  are negative and  this program should find biggest negative element  but when l test program it writes some random number (6784345 instead of array element) can you help me find mistake ?

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<time.h> 
void najneg(int *pa,int *nn) 
{ 
 nn=0;
 for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
  {
    if((pa+i)<nn) nn=(pa+i);
  }
 } 
int main() 
 { 
  int a[20],nn,i; 
  srand(time(0)); 
  for(i=0;i<20;i++) 
   {
    if(i%2==0) a[i]=rand()%(61); 
    else  
    a[i]=(rand()%(61))*(-1); 
   } 
  printf("Formirani niz je:\n");
  for(int i=0;i<20;i++) 
   {
    printf("\ "); printf("%d",a[i]); 
   }
  najneg(a,&nn); 
  printf("\n\nNajveci negativni clan niza je:%d\n",nn); 
  return 0; 
  }
```

Comment: Learn how to index arrays and how to use pointers.  For example, `pa[i]` and `*nn`.   Also, this should be tagged C, not C++, as it is not really C++ code.

Comment: @JoeZ even if l do not understand what you want to say thanks anyway

Comment: @JoeZ Maybe tag it with both, but removing C++ would be weird if he/she's writing C++. Someone might have some `std` related tips for example.

Comment: @user3054839: You need to understand how pointer work.  `(pa+i)` is wrong.

Comment: well l havent  been carefull enough while was working  on this  again thx to everyone

Comment: @Slaks *pa is pointer to a[0]  so  pa+i means nothing  but  *(pa+i) is pointer to a[i]  (at least that's how they thaugt me at school)

Comment: @user3054839: Exactly.  You missed the `*`.

Answer (score 3):

In this code, …

```
void najneg(int *pa,int *nn) 
{ 
 nn=0;
 for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
  {
    if((pa+i)<nn) nn=(pa+i);
  }
}
```

you forgot to **dereference** the pointers,

```
void najneg(int *pa,int *nn) 
{ 
 *nn=0;
 for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
  {
    if(*(pa+i)<*nn) *nn=*(pa+i);
  }
}
```

---

The most important fix for this function is to change its name to something readable and self-descriptive, with no arbitrary shortenings. When choosing names, think about making *the calling code* readable and clear. So E.g., `najneg`  → `most_negative_value_in`.

Secondly, instead of logical out-argument, use the function return value.

Third, if the function doesn't need to change data, use `const` to let it offer a *guarantee* that it won't change the data.

Fourth, avoid **magic numbers** like `20`: pass the array size as argument.

This, plus some purely cosmetic changes, yields:

```
int most_negative_number_in(int const*  const a, int const size) 
{ 
   int n=0;
   for(int i=0; i<size; ++i)
   {
       if(a[i]<n) { n = a[i] };
   }
   return n;
}
```

Comment: You really ought to use standard array indexing here.  `pa[i]`, not `*(pa+i)`.  Every time I see that latter way of indexing a pointer or array I want to claw my eyes out.  It's like writing `(*p).f` instead of `p->f`.

Comment: OMFG lm blind idiot...thx guys first time l tried with that l had mistake in main and removed pointers...now l forgot all about them  thx alot :D

Answer (score 1):

This function should be

```
void najneg(int *pa,int *nn) 
{ 
    *nn=0; //As you want to modify nn.
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
       if(pa[i]<*nn) *nn=pa[i]; //Here, you want to compare values and swap them. Not just address.
    }
}
```

Do not try to complicate it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others have pointed out:

You can simplify the content of your `for` loops:

```
  for(i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
  {
    // The array slot is assigned a random value
    // whether the index is positive or negative.
    a[i] = rand() % 61;

    // If the index is odd, change the value
    // to a negative number.
    if(i % 2 == 1)
    {
      a[i] *= -1;
    }
  }
```

In the next loop, you should combine into one `printf` call:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
  {
    printf("\ %d", a[i]); 
  }
```

Also, what is `"\ "` in the format specifier, a tab or a space?